# How to skip an async call when it doesn't respond

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

I am making an async Http call to one of the integrations in my web application.
Sometimes when the integration is down, it doesn't respond and all the pages from where I am calling the hitting the integration endpoint doesn't load.

```
public static void GetDetails(int Id, string passId)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var result = client.PostAsync("IntegrationEndpoint").Result;
    var jsonResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(jsonResult);
    var code = responseObject.details[0].latestStatus.code;
}
```

Calling the method from my controller:

```
XYZController.GetDetails(Id, passId);
```

How to skip the async call when it does not respond?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but a new `HttpClient` shouldn't be created every call - a singleton or static instance per destination endpoint is usually recommended.
And you shouldn't be doing sync-over async (.Result). - your method should be async, and then use await. You then have the ability to use CancellationTokens with async, which will allow timeout if the endpoint doesn't respond within a timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Then, You may set a timeout value to HttpClient for skipping after a max response time.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

The default value is 100 seconds.

Note: Your function not seems to actually full async. You should change function signature with async Task, and you should use await keyword before the async method calls.